# Meteor http get to Rotten Tomatoes API returns unicode

Tags: javascript, meteor, rotten-tomatoes

I am playing around with the Rotten Tomatoes api and Meteor. If I use `$.ajax` to call the RT api, I get the result as expected. However if I use a Meteor method and http get, I get what appears to be unicode or something.

On the client here's the code. One event uses ajax and the other the Meteor method.

```
Template.hello.events({
  'keyup .search-movies' : function (e, t) {      
    Meteor.call('getMovies', $(e.currentTarget).val(), function(err, resp){
      if(err) console.log(err);
      else console.log(resp);
    });
  },
  'click .click': function(e){
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?apikey=XXX&q=Toy+Story+3&page_limit=1",
      dataType: 'jsonp',
    }).done(function(result) {
      console.log(result);
    });
  }
});
```

On the server for the Meteor method

```
Meteor.methods({
    getMovies: function(query){ 
        var result = HTTP.call("GET", "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?apikey=XXX&q=Toy+Story+3&page_limit=1");
        if (result.statusCode === 200) {
            //var respJson = JSON.parse(result.content);
            console.log(result.content);
            return result.content;
        } 
    }
});
```

And the result from the ajax is good,

```json
{"total":1,"movies":[{"id":"770672122","title":"Toy Story 3","year":2010,"mpaa_rating":"G","runtime":103,"critics_consensus":"Deftly blending comedy, adventure, and honest emotion, Toy Story 3 is a rare second sequel that really works.","release_dates":{"theater":"2010-06-18","dvd":"2010-11-02"},"ratings":
```

but from the http get is not

> I20140209-00:16:27.578(0)?
>   \u001f�\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0003 ...

Does anybody know what's going on? If I am doing something silly or missing something obvious please let me know.

Comment: looks like your $.ajax call is from browser and HTTP.call is from Server side. Does it make any difference to Roten Tomatoes api?

Comment: And did you try looking at result.data?

Comment: @imslavko I came back to look at this about 5 hours later without changing anything and the server side http get now works. Weird! Trying on client side results in a cross domain error.

Comment: it sounds like an inconsistent API behavior but if you continue facing problems, try to check if it is reproducible with other api. If so, open a github issue with a reproduction, thank you